# How To Pass Column Name As Parameter In Loop To Build Tables - R

Tags: r

I have a vector of column names that I pulled from a data frame:

`x = names(myDataSet)`

I want to build tables for data exploration by passing each column name into a for loop and generate each table against a specific named column 'verdict' separately.  I have tried the following:

```
for (i in x){
  table(myDataSet$i, myDataSet$verdict)
}
```

and

```
for (i in x){
  table(myDataSet[[i]], myDataSet$verdict)
}
```

But nothing has worked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to use eval function - or basically instead of addressing to DF like that, find the index and use index instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value)

Comment: What did not work? It seems to me that the second solution should work , but you need to use `print` to actually print the result when you are inside a for-loop

Comment: @J.C.Wahl, that was it!  Thank you.